# vim editor creates additional file having "~" after the end of file name

Tags: vim

Hi I have followed the vimtutor and finished it. After that when I am using vim editor it create backup file as follows

```
filename.xxx~
```

does any one know why its create that file and how can I stop that.

Comment: This might help: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_swap_and_backup_files_from_your_working_directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following two lines into the .vimrc file in your home folder

```
$ vi ~/.vimrc
```

add following two lines in to the end of the file

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
```